# Android Launcher Icon Resize - Composite script

Tags: android, bash, imagemagick, image-resizing

I wanted to create a bash script which resizes a 512x512 Icon to the different android launcher icon sizes.

After the resize the image should be overlayed with a specific logo.png to keep the logo pixelperfect and sharp.

Also the filename should match the icon size.

I've already created a script, but it is not very flexible and pretty repetitive.

How can I make it more compact (reduce copy/paste)?

```
#!/bin/sh

offset_512=27
offset_144=10
offset_96=5
offset_72=5
offset_48=3
offset_36=2


for file in _screens/*.source.png;

    do convert $file -monitor \
        -resize 512x512 \
        _assets/logo-512x512.png \
        -gravity south \
        -geometry +0+${offset_512} \
        -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-512x512.png

        convert $file -monitor \
            -resize 144x144 \
            _assets/logo-144x144.png \
            -gravity south \
            -geometry +0+${offset_144} \
            -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-144x144.png

        convert $file -monitor \
            -resize 96x96 \
            _assets/logo-96x96.png \
            -gravity south \
            -geometry +0+${offset_96} \
            -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-96x96.png

        convert $file -monitor \
            -resize 72x72 \
            _assets/logo-72x72.png \
            -gravity south \
            -geometry +0+${offset_72} \
            -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-72x72.png

        convert $file -monitor \
            -resize 48x48 \
            _assets/logo-48x48.png \
            -gravity south \
            -geometry +0+${offset_48} \
            -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-48x48.png

        convert $file -monitor \
            -resize 36x36 \
            _assets/logo-36x36.png \
            -gravity south \
            -geometry +0+${offset_36} \
            -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-36x36.png

done
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How would i go about simplifying this script and make it more easily changeable?
(Like a variable for each size, or single function for the convert with these values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly other ways to go about this, but an associative array is what came to mind. I do not have the same environment as you in which to test it, but this should be close enough to get the job done. Let me know how it works out.

```
declare -A sizes
sizes=([512x512]=27 [144x144]=10 [96x96]=5 [72x72]=5 [48x48]=3 [36x36]=2)

for file in _screens/*.source.png; do
    for size in "${!sizes[@]}"; do
        convert $file -monitor -resize $size _assets/logo-${size}.png -gravity south -geometry +0+${sizes[$size]} -composite ${file%\.source.png*}-${size}.png
    done
done
```